# Ruby on Rails accessing SQL Server Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

I am using Ruby on Rails with ting_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter to access a MS SQL Server database.

I have all the tables set up but I am not able to set up the Views.

There is a view called dbo.vwJobShipTo.

In my model, I put the following:

```
class vwJobShipTo < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "vwJobShipTo"
  self.primary_key = "JobShipToId"


end
```

I am getting "NameError: undefined local variable or method `vwJobShipTo' for main:Object"

Any idea what I am missing? Any help / advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
class vwJobShipTo
```

to:

```
class VWJobShipTo
```